# my nasted rails form is in infinity loop on self join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I have a self join table in rails but the view is giving infinity loop, any way to prevent this?

#### Node Model

```rb
has_many :child, class_name: 'Node', foreign_key: :parent_id, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Node', foreign_key: "parent_id", primary_key: 'id', optional: true

### template node 

= f.input :name
= f.fields_for :child
= f.link_to_add t('.add_child'), :child

### template child 

= f.input :name
= f.fields_for :child # this line and below line is causing the infinity loop
= f.link_to_add t('.add_child'), :child
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get what you are trying to do. Why is the template for child calling `f.fields_for :child` ? Makes no sense for me, `f` should in this case be child? When you do a self join, you should ref the templates as the relationship names. So `parent` and `child` and not use `node`. Anyway, the problem here is most likely that you have not added `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.